# Using VS2012 diff tool from console

Tags: visual-studio, merge, diff, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to use VS 2012 diff tool from console like below?

```
compare.exe c:\file1 c:\file2
```

**[EDIT](http://homenko.net/post/2013/05/02/Running-VS-2012-difference-tool-from-Console)**

1. Also you can run diff tool from [Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) and it will run in the same instance of VS.

   ```
   Tools.DiffFiles c:\file1 c:\file2
   ```
2. Moreover there is an [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56f99a33-46b9-4d9e-8145-900aaba9951d) for VS 2012.

Comment: do you refer to google chrome's console ?

Comment: please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752998/compare-two-files-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
devenv /diff c:\file1 c:\file2
```

Comment: Thank you! Just want to note that this option is available only for VS11.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke merging via console? `devenv /diff file1 file2 baseFile mergedFile` does not work

Answer (score 0):

To open the **Visual Studio Code Diff Tool** from `cmd` or `powershell` you can enter the following command and need to specify your files of course:

```
code --diff <path1> <path2>
```