# how to compare two files in visual studio ignoring casing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to compare two files in visual studio (files containing stored procs)
So I want to ignore all the `"Capital" / "Small"` differences in the file.

I opened the command window and used `Tools.DiffFiles` but its taking the case difference also into consideration

P.S I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752998/compare-two-files-in-visual-studio-2012) question and answers for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Visual Studio is asked for explicitly, I recommend a different tool: [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

It indeed has many options for comparing and merging files. It lacks a 3-way-merge though. Of course WinMerge can optionally ignore case.

Visual Studio can be configured so you can call WinMerge using "Tools / External Tools ...". Then you may even install a toolbar item for it. Quite nice!

Most version control systems allow you to use WinMerge as a compare tool. For example for TFS you open the "Tools / Options ..." menu and there you choose "Source Control / Visual Studio Team Foundation Server". Click on the button "Configure User Tools".

Comment: I can second the use of WinMerge... I have it as my default comparison tool for TortoiseHG / VisualHG.  And also provides Windows Explorer extensions for direct comparison of files or directories