# Merge two versions of C# projects

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, documentation, sandcastle

I am working on documenting a winForms project that isn't completely done being written, meaning there is another programmer who write the code right now. So I've already wrote some importent comments in a copy of the project.
In addition I use sandcastle to bulid the help file.

My question: what is the best way (if there is one) to copy the comments from the old copy of the project to the new version of it?
Maybe sandcastle can do something like import a documentation to a project?

I know it wasn't so smart to do so, still I have to check if there is a way to save the documentation work.

Comment: The c# is a text file so using a text comparison tool like BeyondCompare may work.

Comment: It's a concern which should be solved using source control tools features and mechanisms. It depends on the strategy of your team working with source control. You may put documentations on the original source code or on another branch different than development branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a built in file difference function you can use to see where the two files are different. It should be then a matter of copy and paste of the changes you have made over to the "gold" copy of the file your other programmer has changed.

This link shows how to [Compare two files in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752998/compare-two-files-in-visual-studio-2012)

"You can invoke devenv.exe /diff list1.txt list2.txt from the command prompt or, if a Visual Studio instance is already running, you can type Tools.DiffFiles in the Command window"

Comment: that's nice i was not familiar with that function of VS, thank you! but in that way i would have to compare each class alone and not the whole project, which means i would need to invest some serious time... i can compared the XML files of the two projects, but this won't add the comments to the actual code. do you know another way to add the written comments?

Comment: Load the original version of the project into a source code control system (TFS or Visual Studio Online). Copy your more recent code into the working folder, then compare the whole project structure.