# Open two files for comparison

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-comparison, winmerge

From Solution Explorer, I'd like to select two C# code files for textual comparison. I have got **WinMerge** installed on my machine, which accepts multiple file names on the command line. So I tried to use **Open With...** command and add WinMerge to the list of existing options. The problem however is that I don't know what to write in the **Arguments** textbox. Setting it to **%1** simply sends the first selected file to WinMerge. **%2** is not recognized by VS and is literally pasted into WinMerge.

What is the correct syntax to send two files?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? "Compare" is already built in, and can be invoked from the "Source Control" context menu (i.e. right-click a file in SE).

Comment: @KennethK.: VS2017 Community. My project is under GIT.

Comment: @KennethK.: "Source Control" is not in my context menu.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752998/compare-two-files-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [File Differ](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileDiffer) extension by Mads Kristensen. It uses the differencer you have configured for Visual Studio.