# How to get Visual Studio 2019 to compare files side by side again?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I recently up dated my Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.18 and now when I compare files (git Compare with unmodified... or [Tools.DiffFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664677/641833)) it shows the differences in one window instead of the side-by-side view I used before.

How do I change it back so one version is on the left and the other on the right?

I tried googling but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button to change this might be hidden out of view in the toolbar.  Click the arrow for the "Compare Files Toolbar options" and then add or remove buttons.  Toggle the Compare View mode option:

[image: compare files toolbar options]

This should add this icon to the toolbar, and then from there you can switch modes:

[image: toolbar option]

Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to change back to side by side mode.